# Using Any data type in Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing a generic spark job where I do not know the aggregate keys beforehand. The intention is that a user can select any random column and the job will start creating aggregates based on that. Lets take a small sample for example

```
Col_A Int
Col_B String
Col_C Long
```

A user can select any of them in the group by clause and select a measure. This job has to now run as a stream.

For implementing this, created an object

```
class AggregateValue(var value: Any)
```

This object will hold the value of the key. Since I do not know the type, I am keeping as **Any**. Now, I want to understand if Any is the best option to do this. Is there any disadvantage of using Any as the type in terms of performance etc.

Also, I understand type safety is a problem with Any. Do you guys expect any performance impact or other impact due to this.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: short answer, you should never use `Any`, losing all the typesafety

Comment: You defenitly don't want to use Any, i guess you can use generic class over here maybe (if your column types is not a huge number).

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the generic class. I am new to this and it will help

Comment: You probably want `class Aggregate[T](t: T)`

Answer (score 2):

If you google here and elsewhere you will find that UDFs cannot use Any nor a map.

Spark SQL and DFs and DSs do not support Any in a schema. So, it is not a good idea.

I have encountered an Any on occasion and it cannot really be solved.

In short: Any type is a signal to look for other ways to do things.

Comment: Thanks. I was using RDD for my processing, hence the process seems to work. But I am not sure of the impact of Any on performance etc. Can you suggest another approach to this. Just a snippet would do

Comment: Will look later but there are issues with rdd as well. Rdd is also legacy

Comment: Thanks. I wanted some transformations on data, hence used RDD. something like one row needs to be converted to multiple rows with different schema

Comment: on thin ice, believe me and others who are far smarter, Any Type to be voided at all costs